# More connections than thread handlers

Tags: java, spring, rest, scalability

Say I have two endpoints in my API (in Spring as previously):

```
@RequestMapping("/async")
public CompletableFuture<String> g(){
    CompletableFuture<String> f = new CompletableFuture<>();
    f.runAsync(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            f.complete("Finished");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    return f;
}

@RequestMapping("/sync")
public String h() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    return "Finished";
}
```

When I send 2 get requests (just single get requests) to:

`localhost:8080/async` --> response in `5024ms`

`localhost:8080/sync` --> response in '6055ms`

This makes sense because we are sending just a *single* request. Now things get interesting when I do a load test with Siege involving 255 concurrent users.

In this case, my `async` API endpoint isn't able to handle many connections.

So `async` is not as scalable.

Does this depend on my hardware? Say I had hardware able to handle more thread-handlers, then with heavy hardware, would the async one be able to handle more transactions since there are more threads?

Comment: Still working on this, huh?

Comment: Did you get Exception? Error?

Comment: @Kayaman, its just curiosity; I'm interested in infrastructure, but can't find enough info on this.

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing with the internet. Lack of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're still using the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` for your async invocations. I told you it's small and it will get filled up. Try this (I fixed your `CompletableFuture` code too, as it's totally wrong, it just doesn't show in your example).

```
CompletableFuture<Void> f = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
return f;
```

Now each async call gets its own executor, so it doesn't choke on the common pool. Of course since all async calls get their own executor, this is a bad example. You'd want to use a shared pool, but something larger than the common pool.

It has nothing (well, very little) to do with your hardware. It has everything to do with long running operations intermingled with short running operations.

Comment: Thanks! I have been doing some more research. However, when I seriously overloaded the server (many many threads) I got the "Out of native threads error." What is a way to counter this?

Comment: By creating fewer threads. The server limits the regular request worker threads, but the async one in my example creates a thread every time, as explained in the answer.

Comment: I've created an ExecutorService (did some research) with `newCachedPoolThread`, so now the server is doing good. Is this a good approach?